# WPF ContentControl some unclears

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

i have some usercontrols in my solution, in main window i just change content of ContentControl.
in one usercontrol there is a timer

```
    BringTrinket trincket = new BringTrinket();
    trincket.TrincketBringed += new TrincketBringedEventHandler(trincket_TrincketBringed);
    this.contentSwitcher.Content = new BringTrinket();
    }

    void trincket_TrincketBringed(object sender, TrincketEventArgs e)
    {            
        MessageBox.Show(e.TrincketNumber);
        this.contentSwitcher.Content = new Loading();
    }`
```

after some event Main Window should change content to (new Loading()), it's OK!

```
public partial class BringTrinket : UserControl, ISwitchable
{
    public event TrincketBringedEventHandler TrincketBringed;

    private DispatcherTimer timer;

    public BringTrinket()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1800);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TrincketBringed != null)
        {
            TrincketBringed(this, new TrincketEventArgs("Hello"));
            //TrincketBringed = null;
        }
    }
```

But after i've navigataged Timer in BringTrinket still working, how have i dispose that usercontrol? (I know i can set TrincketBringed to null, but timer will still be working)

I think not only timer, but also usercontrol remains in memory

Answer (score 0):

So, your question is how to stop the timer? Use `timer.Stop()`.
BTW, your code would read better if you rename `TricketBringed` to `TrincketBrought`.

Comment: Thanks, my english is not very well :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your timer is inside of your first usercontrol. You would either need to stop the timer before losing the reference to that object, or better yet, move the timer out of your control.

Comment: I think not only timer, but also usercontrol remains in memory